# Compare values of two columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document like:

```
Name    Mark
A        1
B        1
A        1
B        2
```

From this, I need to find that `A` with the mark of `1` and I want to delete the duplicated one.

Can anyone please suggest how to do it, with macro or any other tools?

Comment: Could you try formatting your excel example please.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Answer (score 0):

Select both columns and use the `Remove Duplicates` tool in the `Data` tab